# Introducing a String to define a type

Tags: java

I want to know if there is a way to do this:

`String **type** = "Player"`

`ArrayList<**type**> players = new ArrayList();`

What I mean is defining an object type with a variable String. I put "player" and it can just be `Player` here, but what about a method that you can introduce a variable type to? Something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

   system.out.println("Select a type that u wanna make an array of");

   system.out.println("1. Player");
   system.out.println("2. Team");

   Scanner in = new Scaner (System.in);

   createArray(in.next());
}

public static void createArray(String **type**)
{

 ArrayList<**type**> x = new ArrayList();

}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: If there is a common interface between them, you can do something sane that doesn't work like this.  If not, then your code wont make any sense anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is possible with annotations and a custom annotation processor (but probably not a good idea).

Then your code would look like

```
@StringlyType String type="Player"
```

and you would would have to write a custom annotation processor that whenever it encounters a `@StringlyType` annotation creates a class as the other answers suggest.

**But What is the Point?**

Disclaimer:  I have not actually tried any of this; nor do I intend to.  So I can not guarantee it works.

Comment: Honestly, that would be an entertaining GitHub project.  But there is orders of magnitude more work involved in creating *everything* needed for that annotation processor than simply creating the class.

Comment: @Makoto I left that as an exercise for the OP.  It would be cool if s/he does it and posts a github link.  I would probably look at it, but not use it.

Comment: Wow, you are actually right that it can be done this way but honestly, I highly discourage creating such abominations

Comment: Well, the point is that i wanna search in a db4o database and I have 4 kinds of class in that database. Then when i want to get an object I could just use this to get one or other class with the same method depending on what (String "class") I introduce.

Comment: @Alejandro93sa I think in java http://stackoverflow.com/a/35674234/348975 is the best answer.  I would discourage my answer (which is technically correct, but practically almost useless).  If you wanted to try other JVM languages then I think this would be easier in Clojure.

Answer (score 8):

Run *away* from [Stringly-typed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) thinking and simply create your own class to capture all of the information you would want about a player.

```
public class Player {
    // fields, methods to describe a player
}

public class Team {
    // fields, methods to describe a team
}
```

Then, your `ArrayList` would work as you expect it to.

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
```

As a side note:  your current code structure would only create the list in that method and it wouldn't be available afterwards.  If you want it back, you'd have to return `ArrayList<Player>`, or alternatively, declare it inside of `main` when you go to use it.

Comment: I though in that solution to re-use many code, but it seems imposible as some people told me. Thanks a lot for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for doing this:

Generic types are only for compilation time type checking you need to understand this, they are not needed for what you are doing (determining the generic type at runtime).

You can simply do

```
List objects = new ArrayList();
```

and proceed to put any type into it but you will obviously have to cast the objects to the correct type before using them after taken out of the list.